# WebLogic: can't get roles for user in EJB3

Tags: java, security, ejb-3.0, weblogic, weblogic11g

In my EJB 3 I try to test for the roles of the principal but it always returns `false`.

In my WebLogic 11g Console I defined under "MyDomain" -> "Security Realms" -> "myrealm" -> "Users and Groups" 3 users (user1 , user2 & user3) and 2 groups (role1 & role2); role1 has user1 & user3, role2 has user2 & user3.
My EJB has no further security defined (no `@RolesAllowed`, etc. or entries in DDs).

When I test in my EJB for the presence of roles with `sessionContext.isCallerInRole(role);` it **always** returns `false`. If I call `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();` I do get the correct user ID.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might help to know which exact version of Weblogic 11g you have. I have recent, sharp, and unpleasant experience that EJB and Jax-Ws behavior and bugs are sharply different between the various editions of Weblogic labeled 10.3.0, 10.3.1, 10.3.3 and 10.3.4, all but the first labeled 11g.

Comment: It's `WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your role using either @DeclareRoles or  ? If I read the spec correctly section 17.2.5.3 seems to mandate that you have to declare any role names that you use when calling isCallerInRole() through one or the other mechanism.

Comment: You seem to be correct. The docs all tell to add `@DeclareRoles()` or specify them in the descriptor.  But even when I add `@DeclareRoles({ "role1", " role2" })` it doesn't work.

Comment: Additionally, to make this work I had to change Security Model for the EAR to "CustomRoles". I did this by changing the security realm default setting but you could also do it in the deployer. Also, obviously I created a global role in admin console that has the same name as the role name referenced in the EJB and has a role condition that maps to the group that a user has to belong to in order to have the role.

Answer (score 0):

If your `sessionContext` is injected, specifying the authentication Type as Container in the `@Resource` annotation worked for me. 
E.g.:

```
@Resource(authenticationType=AuthenticationType.CONTAINER)
private SessionContext sessionCtx;
```